# Stripe: StripeInvalidRequestError Error: No such token: btok_1CQUtNI6UceP4uARenSx4Cjo

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect, plaid

I've created a bank account token from Plaid and now I want to use that bank token with Stripe but I get this error `No such token: btok_1CQUtNI6UceP4uARenSx4Cjo`

I'm using Plaid sandbox environment and Stripe test keys

I'm following this (https://plaid.com/docs/link/stripe) and I've done till step 4. Plaid creates a btok for me but Stripe doesn't accept it.

The detailed Stripe response is in the image [image: Stripe response]

Answer (score 2):

Stripe Tokens can only be used by the api keys of the account that created them (otherwise trying to use them will return a `resource_missing` error).  Double check [in your Stripe dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys) that the public key you are using to create the bank account token, and the secret key you are creating this request with belong to the same account.

If you want details about which accounts the bank account token or request were made from, please don't hesitate to write into support@stripe.com.

Comment: Thankyou! I'm not using a public key to create the bank account token. I'm using Plaid's credentials to create a token.

Comment: @AlamgirQazi ah, in that case check that the Account ID you pass into Plaid's createStripeToken function is from the same Stripe account as your secret key.

https://plaid.com/docs/link/stripe/

Comment: I'm using sandbox environment. When I login to any bank using plaid's test credentials: user_good and pass_good, I get 4 accounts in response. It creates stripe bank tokens for all 4 accounts but When I try to add them to connect account or to a customer, It gives me no such token error. For credit card, it gives a different error that it's not a depository account.

Stripe are saying that the bank account token isn't created on my account while Plaid are saying its been created with sandbox environment and I'm processing them with Stripe live environment (not true) as I'm using test keys

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had multiple Stripe accounts and was using the Stripe account keys which weren't linked to Plaid.

Comment: how did you link Stripe to Paid? when i click on *Connect with stripe* button from Plaid Dashboard [integration](https://dashboard.plaid.com/account/integrations), stripe request me to fill out business and bank details although i am using stripe sandbox so don't have all those details. not sure how did you manage to integrate stripe with Plaid while both are in sandbox mode?

Comment: I had my client do this as he filled out the Stripe details. I think it's necessary otherwise your Plaid account doesn't get linked

Comment: Yeah.. i did same as well. filled out stripe bank and business details after reach out to stripe support and they said `You have to provide these details` Thanks @Alamgir

Answer (score 0):

Posting as may be helpful to someone struggling with this error. Try following

1. Make sure your secret(backend) and publishable(frontend) keys belongs to same account.
2. Consider my case where I was passing connected account as stripe account more than once. (using source for payments and having same issue 'No such token: src_xxxxxx'.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the stripe.js file update code with own publishable key

```
// Set your publishable key: remember to change this to your live publishable key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys

    var stripe = Stripe('StripeKey');
    var elements = stripe.elements();
```